# A cursor track left on the screen

Tags: display, cursor

When I move mouse, there will be a cursor track left on the screen, shown in figure. How can I fix it? The figure link is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtwoklxl3n4m74r/2014-12-24%2003.41.27.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: You can check this by restarting the machine once and check whether the cursor track left issue get rid off or not.

Comment: unfortunately, it still has the track. I use the latest version.